# Workaround for CakePHP tests with enums?

Tags: unit-testing, cakephp, testing, enums, cakephp-2.4

I try to create unit tests for CakePHP project. After creating fixtures and some tests I run into problems:

> Warning: Column type enum('on','off') does not exist in
>   /app/cake/2.4.7/Cake/Model/Datasource/DboSource.php
>   on line 3081
>
> ...
>
> Application error: called handler method exception 'PDOException' with
>   message 'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column
>   'state' in 'field list'' in
>   /app/cake/2.4.7/Cake/Model/Datasource/DboSource.php:2923

I know that CakePHP does not support enum but I cannot change the datatype. Is there any workaround to get unit tests running with enums?

Comment: can you not create your fixtures using text fields?

Comment: I haven't tried yet. I have a table with 33 columns and I use `public $import = 'MyModel';`. It will be quite tedious to define all the columns manually :(.

Comment: If the unit tests fail on the enums, why doesn't the app?

Comment: I think because the application uses the database with existing tables and the unit tests try to read the existing schema, create tables, insert some data and then run the tests. So, the errors occur somewhere in the process of retrieving the existing schema and creating tables.

Comment: I guess, unit tests omit enum columns while creating tables.

Comment: Probably what you need to do to get that to work is to override the schema method in the model (you can do this in your app model) such that it does not report having enum fields, but instead text fields. That will mean the fixture manager [never hears that you're feeding it enum fields](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/lib/Cake/TestSuite/Fixture/CakeTestFixture.php#L139) and quite possibly fix some other quirks with dealing with legacy dbs. You may find that your changes are [appropriate to submit as a patch to CakePHP](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/issues/2637).

Answer (score 7):

I ran into the same problem. To solve I created a subclass that extends the CakeTestFixture class and overrides the creation of the table to re-map all enum fields to strings.

```
<?php

class MyTestFixture extends CakeTestFixture {

  /**
   * Maps enum fields in the database to strings with a length of 64
   */
  function create(&$db) {
    foreach($this->fields as $name => &$field) {
      if( strstr($field['type'], "enum") !== false ) {
        $field['type'] = 'string';
        $field['length'] = 64;
      }
    }
    parent::create($db);
  }
}
```

To use this, just extend this class in your fixture as opposed to CakeTestFixture.

```
<?php

App::uses('MyTestFixture', 'WhereverYouPutIt');

class MyTableFixture extends MyTestFixture {
    public $import = array('model' => 'MyTable');
}
```

Comment: Why the reference in create(&$db)? At least that results in php complaining that it does not match parent's create($db) declaration.